# Ormlite subquery in select

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, ormlite, query-builder

How execute subquery in select using Ormlite. I try this

```
QueryBuilder<Group, Long> queryBuilder = groupDAO.queryBuilder();
            queryBuilder.selectColumns(BaseColumns._ID ,Group.COLUMN_TITLE, "(SELECT relation_type FROM groupmembership as gr WHERE `group`._ID = gr.group_id AND gr.user_id = 687)");
```

but get exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name '(SELECT relation_type FROM groupmembership as gr WHERE `group`._ID = gr.group_id AND gr.user_id = 687)' in table groups
```

By the way. I know about `rawQuery`(), but I want use `QueryBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible because `QueryBuilder.selectColumns()` check column names before adding to query.

I found this in source

```
private void addSelectColumnToList(String columnName) {
    verifyColumnName(columnName);
    selectColumnList.add(columnName);
}
```